# property of harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions

If a real-valued function $u$ is harmonic on a ball $B_{2r}(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how would one show that

$$\sup_{B_r(x)}u^2\leq\frac{2^n}{|B_{2r}(x)|}\int_{B_{2r}(x)}u^2(y) dy$$

Answer (score 2):

$\def\vol{\operatorname{vol}}$For $y \in B_r(x)$ by the mean value property and Hölder
\begin{align*}
  u^2(y) &= \left(\frac 1{\vol B_r(y)}\int_{B_r(y)}u(z)\,dz\right)^2\\
    &\le \frac 1{\vol B_r(y)^2} \int_{B_r(y)} u^2(z)\,dz \cdot \int_{B_r(y)} 1^2\,dz\\
    &= \frac 1{\vol B_r(y)} \int_{B_r(y)} u^2(z)\,dz
\end{align*}
Now, as $B_r(y) \subseteq B_{2r}(x)$ and $\vol B_{2r} = 2^n \vol B_r$, we have
\begin{align*}
  {u^2(y)} &\le \frac {2^n}{\vol B_{2r}(x)}\int_{B_{2r}(x)} u^2(z)\, dz
\end{align*}
And hence, as $y \in B_r(x)$ was arbitrary
\[ \sup_{B_r(x)} u^2 \le  \frac {2^n}{\vol B_{2r}(x)}\int_{B_{2r}(x)} u^2(z)\, dz
\]

Comment: Shouldn't the second $=$ be $\le$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Of course you're right, thanks.